# Spring Security Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-security

When ever i navigate to authenticated url, all the static contents even the url's inside href has been attached with the route's url because of that i'm getting 404 for all the resources in that page and all the urls inside href element

for e.x

```
    <security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="false"> 
            <security:intercept-url pattern="/reports/**" access="ROLE_USER"/>
            <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS"/>

            <security:form-login login-page="/login.do" login-processing-url="/login.do" username-parameter="custom_username" 
                password-parameter="custom_password"
                 authentication-success-handler-ref="authSuccessHandler"
                default-target-url="/"
                always-use-default-target="true"
                authentication-failure-url="/login.do?error=true"/>
                <security:logout logout-url="/logout.do" logout-success-url="/login.do?logout=true"/>
            <security:csrf disabled="true"/>
        </security:http >

        <security:authentication-manager>
            <security:authentication-provider>
                <security:user-service>
                    <security:user name="user1" password="password" authorities="ROLE_USER"/>
                    <security:user name="admin" password="password" authorities="ROLE_USER,ROLE_FOO"/>
                </security:user-service>
            </security:authentication-provider>
        </security:authentication-manager>
<security:http  pattern="**/styles/**"  security="none" />
<security:http  pattern="**/js/**"  security="none" />
```

When i navigate to **myapp/reports/** my static contents have been changed to

[image]

normally in html it looks like

```html
<link href="styles/jqueryUI.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/Home.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/metisMenu.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/sideBar.css">
```

Something i missed here even i have enebled mvc:resources

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
<mvc:resources mapping="/WebContent/styles/**" location="css/"  />
<mvc:resources mapping="/WebContent/js/**" location="js/"  />
<mvc:resources mapping="/WebContent/images/**" location="images/"  />
<mvc:resources mapping="/WebContent/fonts/**" location="fonts/"  />
```

Comment: Your question not clear?

Answer (score 1):

There are problems at your resource mapping and href attribute of link tag. 
As you have not posted your directory structure
Let me explain how to do sample map:
Here is my directory structure : 
[image]

If I want to add customestyle.min.css to my html page I need the following settings :

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/contents/css/**" location="/contents/css/" />
```

and

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href='<c:url value="/contents/css/customestyle.min.css"/> '/>
```